# Adding percentage after a vector of values in R and enclose each value with single quotation marks

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse

I have vectors like this

```
w <- 'j309'
x <- 'j309,j405,j667'
y <- 'j309, j405, j667, j666'
z <- 'j309, j405, j667,j662'
```

I pass these vectors into a SQL query and so would like to convert these vectors to my desired form by adding a percentage after every value. It should be able to correct any white spaces in the vector too.

My **desired output** is

```
'j309%'
'j309%','j405%','j667%'
'j309%','j405%','j667%','j666%' 
'j309%','j405%','j667%','j662%'
```

I am trying to do it this way but not able to get it right

```
gsub(",", "%", x)
```

How to achieve this desired output using R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a function with `gsub` to either replace the `,` or at the end (`$`) of the stirng with `%,` then remove the `,` at the end with `trimws` from `base R`

```
f1 <-  function(x) trimws(gsub("$|,\\s*", "%, ", x), whitespace = ",\\s*")
```

Now, check the application of the function

```
f1(x)
#[1] "j309%, j405%, j667%"

f1(z)
#[1] "j309%, j405%, j667%, j662%"

f1(y)
#[1] "j309%, j405%, j667%, j666%"
f1(w)
#[1] "j309%"
```

#### Update

based on the update from OP, we can modify the function to

```
f2 <- function(x) gsub("(\\w+)", "'\\1%'", x)
f2(x)
#[1] "'j309%','j405%','j667%'"
f2(z)
#[1] "'j309%', 'j405%', 'j667%','j662%'"
f2(y)
#[1] "'j309%', 'j405%', 'j667%', 'j666%'"
f2(x)
#[1] "'j309%','j405%','j667%'"
```

#### Update2

If we need to split up the string into substring

```
f3 <- function(x) paste0(unlist(strsplit(x, ",\\s*")), "%")
f3(x)
#[1] "j309%" "j405%" "j667%"
f3(z)
#[1] "j309%" "j405%" "j667%" "j662%"
f3(y)
#[1] "j309%" "j405%" "j667%" "j666%"

f3(w)
#[1] "j309%"
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer but my desired output is slightly different. I need to add ' ' between every value. instead of "j309%,j405%" it should be 'j309%',j405%'. Can you please check?

Comment: @Sharath sure, I will do that

Comment: @Sharath do you need `gsub("(\\w+)", "'\\1%'", y)`

Comment: I think this gets close to what I want but when I use vecs = c(f2(y)), it goes as a Parenthesized expression but I would like to get vecs as a character with 4 values. If we remove the "double quotes", will it help? I would like to get it in this format vecs=c('j309%', 'j405%', 'j667%', 'j666%') so the class is character with 4 values. Let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: @Sharath In that case, you just need `paste0(unlist(strsplit(w, ",\\s*")), "%")`

Comment: @Sharath please check the update.  I think what you need is a splitted vector of substrings

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
x <- c('j309', 'j309,j405,j667', 'j309, j405, j667, j666', 'j309, j405, j667,j662')
paste0("'", gsub("(\\d),\\s*", "\\1%','", sub("(.*\\d)$", "\\1%", x)), "'")
```

See [R proof](https://tio.run/##K/r/v0LBRlchWUM9y9jAUl1HAUzrZJkYmOpkmZmZw0UUwEIKIDEwaYZVBkgYqWtyFSQWl6QaaCipK@kopBeXJmkoacTEpGjqxMQUawGFlGJiDFXVdUCyEEk9LZC0CkwKSFdoagI56kqa//8DAA), results:

```
[1] "'j309%'"                         "'j309%','j405%','j667%'"        
[3] "'j309%','j405%','j667%','j666%'" "'j309%','j405%','j667%','j662%'"
```

1. `sub("(.*\\d)$", "\\1%", x)` adds `%` at the end of string if it ends with a digit
2. `gsub("(\\d),\\s*", "\\1%','"` adds `%','` after each digit that has a comma and spaces  behind it

Comment: Thanks for this answer but my desired output is slightly different. I need to add ' ' between every value. instead of "j309%,j405%" it should be 'j309%',j405%'. Can you please check?

Comment: @Sharath Is input like I have used?

Comment: Yes it is like that you have used.

Comment: @Sharath I am afraid it cannot be achieved with one `gsub`, the replacements differ.